# laptop bios won't show on second monitor

Tags: boot, laptop, multiple-monitors, bios

I recently got a laptop with a cracked screen from a good friend of mine and need to enter the bios to boot from USB. I've disconnected the ribbon connector to the screen from the board and still the bios will not show on my monitor, I have tried holding (fn) and pressing (f7) to switch the display once in bios and still no luck. I can not get into this computer to be able to change what closing the lid does to boot with it closed please any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!!! I am losing my mind I've been trying to get this to work for three days on and off!

the laptop is a Clevo P950hp6 here is a link to the manual : https://www.e-weekly.co.uk/download/RnD/DRIVERS/CLEVO/P950HP6/Manual.pdf

Comment: `disconnected the ribbon connector to the screen` won't make the system believe there's no screen

Comment: This has been asked a million times already and the only proper answer is replace the screen

Comment: actually disconnecting the ribbon connecter usually forces the laptop default to the second screen

Comment: here is a video for some of you that do not understand what I am talking about I have done this before but never with a Clevo notebook                                                           [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6-3c4oKUUM)